# How to fail on serialization when type was not annotated

Tags: java, json, serialization, polymorphism, jackson

I have a superclass with the following annotations:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "_name")
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(value = Lion.class, name = "lion"), @Type(value = Elephant.class, name = "elephant")})
public abstract class Animal {...}
```

And a class using a collection that stores Animals:

```
public class Zoo {
    List<Animal> animals;
}
```

This works fine as long no new subclasses are used, example output:

```
{"animals":[{"_name":"lion"},{"_name":"elephant"}]}
```

When another type that isn't annotated is used I don't get an exception on serialization but on deserialization - that is to late. **Question:** How to configure Jackson to throw an exception when the type wasn't registered before?

Instead of getting an exception the class name was used (which wasn't configured), eg:

```
{"animals":[{"_name":"lion"},{"_name":"elephant"},{"_name":"Turtle"}]}
```

How I serialize:

```
List<Animal> animals = Lists.newArrayList(lion, elephant);
Zoo zoo = new Zoo(animals);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String zooString = mapper.writeValueAsString(zoo);
```

How I deserialze:

```
Zoo zooDeserialized = mapper.readValue(zooString, Zoo.class);
```

Exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not resolve type id 'Turtle' into a subtype of [simple type, class mypackage.Animal]
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: mypackage.Zoo["animals"])
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
..
```

Comment: This is not a simple task. I believe you'll need to create a `TypeResolverBuilder` and use it while annotating your `Animal` class with `@JsonTypeResolver`.